# Is there a way to limit python's access to storage programmatically?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dynamic, abstract-syntax-tree, restriction

So I had a few unverified scripts which are generated dynamically and are required to run. So I had to limit the access to a module which in my case is `io`, `os`, `shutil`, etc...

Now this is something I have tried

```py
from types import ModuleType

def generate_empty_globals():
    return ModuleType("__main__").__dict__


module_locker = """
import os, sys, io
def empty_module(module):
    for x in dir(module):
        setattr(module, x, None)

empty_module(os)
empty_module(sys)
empty_module(io)
"""
my_module = generate_empty_globals()

code = """ ... """
exec(module_locker, my_module)
exec(code, my_module)
```

Now in the above approach i already import the modules and set every function variable in them to None, so that if the unknown code runs and imports the library, the library would not be re imported because the library was already imported, this provides good level of security but at the same time you have code s like this one

```py
import os 
import importlib

importlib.reload(os)
```

which thus allows them the access the modules once again. So I thought i could block them by blocking the reload method of importlib itself but unfortunately some code that was given relied on that reload ability. Now I had a new idea in my mind which is basically use `ast` to modify the code structure and remove those import statements but I do not know how to do that, so is there any way to do this without relying on platform specific methods.

**edit**

Simply a way to restrict the module access (only). and for allowance of modules I will use a special module or say api.

Comment: What you are looking for seems to be sandboxing. The TLDR is that there is no TLDR. You would have to very precisely specify what you consider "limited access" and what should still work afterwards, and even then there is no guarantee that this is doable. It is generally easier and more robust to isolate scripts via processes, containers, or entire VMs that can be removed after the task.

Comment: For your idea to use ``ast``: Do you really just want to remove ``import`` statements? What about ``__import__``? What about aliases of ``__import__``? What about ``sys.modules``? [What about ``eval``?](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html)

Comment: well really i want to remove everything which maybe used and basically permissions are given when a script interacts with a special api. for example it will query through some kind of api to really get the perms, and the VM, Container is not effeceint when you are running apps very frequently like running through 300 scripts. Also VM is much more of a platform specific feature

Comment: I agree with @MisterMiyagi. It's going to be nearly impossible to account for all unsafe code. Consider writing the generated code to a temporary file and running it using the subprocess module. This would ensure that your current environment is unaffected and better allow you to restrict what the script can and cannot do. If you don't want to run a VM or container, you could, for example, run the subprocess as a different user or use chroot.

Comment: well chroot is not on windows, and running it as a new user, I do not really find it cross-platform. By cross-platform i mean every small to big OS which can support python3 and i really needed a way to do that in python way.

Comment: @xcodz-dot Please be more specific than "remove everything which maybe used" and similar. Sandboxing is a lot of work and using incorrect specifications will make the entire work useless. *What* do you want removed – Python functions? PVM internals? OS calls? How do you expect the script to "request permissions" – what should it use when everything was removed? How does it authenticate? How does the permission-granting-thing decide what is authorised? When you do not want "platform specific methods" – what can it use? Do you need Windows, Linux, MacOS, FreeBSD, ...?

Comment: need to remove access to specific python modules only. Permissions are requested via a API. Authentication is done by asking the user if it wants to allow the access. I want a pure python implementation and i really did not find any through google, stackoverflow, pypi

Comment: The best tools for what you want are going to be OS-level permissions and ulimits, perhaps in combination with something like `firejail`.

Comment: @xcodz-dot Just to be clear: Your goal is merely to remove all variants of ``import`` statements? Regardless of whether that will actually suffice for what you have given as background?

Comment: Basically, Remove import statements in a given source by the name of module. You do not even need to worry about the API which grants permissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me start by saying that I think you should really consider an alternative such as using a subprocess run as a more restricted user. If your hands are tied and you're being forced to implement it this way for some reason, you might want to look into importlib hooks (after you go on the record stating it's a bad idea to solve the problem using import hooks).

From [PEP 302 - New Import Hooks](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0302/#specification-part-2-registering-hooks)

> There are two types of import hooks: Meta hooks and Path hooks. Meta hooks are called at the start of import processing, before any other import processing (so that meta hooks can override sys.path processing, frozen modules, or even built-in modules). To register a meta hook, simply add the finder object to sys.meta_path (the list of registered meta hooks.)

**importlib.abc.[`MetaPathFinder`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.abc.MetaPathFinder)**

> An abstract base class representing a meta path finder. For
> compatibility, this is a subclass of Finder.
>
> New in version 3.3.
>
> **find_spec(fullname, path, target=None)**
>
> An abstract method for finding a spec for the specified module. If
> this is a top-level import, path will be None. Otherwise, this is a
> search for a subpackage or module and path will be the value of
> **path** from the parent package. If a spec cannot be found, None is returned. When passed in, target is a module object that the finder
> may use to make a more educated guess about what spec to return.
> importlib.util.spec_from_loader() may be useful for implementing
> concrete MetaPathFinders.
>
> New in version 3.4.
>
> **find_module(fullname, path)**
>
> A legacy method for finding a loader for the specified module. If this is a top-level import, path will be None. Otherwise, this is a search for a subpackage or module and path will be the value of **path** from the parent package. If a loader cannot be found, None is returned.
>
> If find_spec() is defined, backwards-compatible functionality is provided.
>
> Changed in version 3.4: Returns None when called instead of raising
> NotImplementedError. Can use find_spec() to provide functionality.
>
> Deprecated since version 3.4: Use find_spec() instead.
>
> **invalidate_caches()**
>
> An optional method which, when called, should
> invalidate any internal cache used by the finder. Used by
> importlib.invalidate_caches() when invalidating the caches of all
> finders on sys.meta_path.
>
> Changed in version 3.4: Returns None when called instead of
> NotImplemented.

Just playing around with it a little bit, I was able to make an import hook that will check if the requested module is in a list of approved modules. If it is, it imports the module using the default importers. If not, it raises an error.

I can think of two major problems (and there are surely more) with a solution like this. First, a top-level module can import dozens of other modules. Second, if you ever need to allow a script to import sys or importlib, they could easily find a way around the import restrictions.

```py
import sys
import importlib

class MyImporter():
    original_importers = sys.meta_path
    approved = ['os']
    
    @classmethod
    def find_spec(cls, fullname, path, target=None):
        if fullname not in cls.approved:
            raise RuntimeError('Permission for module {} not approved'.format(fullname))
        for importer in cls.original_importers:
            spec =  importer.find_spec(fullname, path, target)
            if spec is not None:
                return spec
        return None

if __name__ == '__main__':
    importlib.abc.MetaPathFinder.register(MyImporter)
    sys.meta_path = [MyImporter]
    import os
    import argparse # fails because argparse is not in approved modules
```

Comment: That's perfectly what i needed.

Comment: I will make restrictions to importlib, sys as well.